# Theano gradient doesn't work with .sum(), only .mean()?

Tags: machine-learning, theano

I'm trying to learn theano and decided to implement linear regression (using their Logistic Regression from the tutorial as a template). I'm getting a wierd thing where T.grad doesn't work if my cost function uses .sum(), but does work if my cost function uses .mean(). Code snippet:

(THIS DOESN'T WORK, RESULTS IN A W VECTOR FULL OF NANs):

```
x = T.matrix('x')
y = T.vector('y')

w = theano.shared(rng.randn(feats), name='w')
b = theano.shared(0., name="b")

# now we do the actual expressions
h = T.dot(x,w) + b # prediction is dot product plus bias
single_error = .5 * ((h - y)**2)
cost = single_error.sum() 
gw, gb = T.grad(cost, [w,b])

train = theano.function(inputs=[x,y], outputs=[h, single_error], updates = ((w, w - .1*gw), (b, b - .1*gb)))
predict = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=h)

for i in range(training_steps):
    pred, err = train(D[0], D[1])
```

(THIS DOES WORK, PERFECTLY):

```
x = T.matrix('x')
y = T.vector('y')

w = theano.shared(rng.randn(feats), name='w')
b = theano.shared(0., name="b")

# now we do the actual expressions
h = T.dot(x,w) + b # prediction is dot product plus bias
single_error = .5 * ((h - y)**2)
cost = single_error.mean() 
gw, gb = T.grad(cost, [w,b])

train = theano.function(inputs=[x,y], outputs=[h, single_error], updates = ((w, w - .1*gw), (b, b - .1*gb)))
predict = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=h)

for i in range(training_steps):
    pred, err = train(D[0], D[1])
```

The only difference is in the cost = single_error.sum() vs single_error.mean(). What I don't understand is that the gradient should be the exact same in both cases (one is just a scaled version of the other). So what gives?

Answer (score 3):

The learning rate (0.1) is way to big. Using mean make it divided by the batch size, so this help. But I'm pretty sure you should make it much smaller. Not just dividing by the batch size (which is equivalent to using mean).

Try a learning rate of 0.001.

Answer (score 0):

Try dividing your gradient descent step size by the number of training examples.